# PHP Variables are undefined, yet I set them in function

Tags: php, mysql, database, echo

So, I have been writing a bit of PHP, and I am grabbing some data from my database to be outputted. I'm using functions, as a normal person would, but for some reason, my variables, which are declined in the function are apparently undeclared?

Here's my code:

```
function fetchUserData($localUser_id) {

    include_once("../../../conConfig/connectToDatabase.php");

    $dataQuery = mysqli_query($dbConnect, "SELECT users.emailAddress, userInfo.fullName, userInfo.initials, userInfo.maxWorkspaces FROM users INNER JOIN userInfo ON userInfo.ID = users.ID WHERE users.ID = ".$localUser_id."");
    $queryResult = mysqli_fetch_array($dataQuery, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    $db_dash_userName   = $queryResult["fullName"];
    $db_dash_userEmail  = $queryResult["emailAddress"];
    $db_dash_userIcon   = "initials";
    $db_dash_userMaxW   = $queryResult["maxWorkspaces"];
    $db_dash_userInit   = $queryResult["initials"];

    echo $db_dash_userName.$db_dash_userEmail.$db_dash_userIcon.$db_dash_userMaxW.$db_dash_userInit."<br><br><br>";

}

//$localUser_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
$localUser_id = 1;
fetchUserData($localUser_id);

echo $db_dash_userName.$db_dash_userEmail.$db_dash_userIcon.$db_dash_userMaxW.$db_dash_userInit;
```

What could possibly be wrong with it? It's returning a value, as outputted by the echo-ing inside of the function, but they're not being outputted by the final 'echo'.

Yes, I have tried 'return variable.variable...', but that still doesn't resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to return values from the function in place of echoing them.

Comment: You need to learn about variable scopes.

Comment: I have tried "return variables...", but the issue still persists...

Comment: In your case, you might be better off with your function inserting the values in an array and then returning that array. Then you should be able to access those variables from the returned array after you call the function.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return values from function.  echoing does not return values.  Also you need to assign the returned values into a variable and use it to display the output.

```
function fetchUserData($localUser_id) {

        include_once("../../../conConfig/connectToDatabase.php");

        $dataQuery = mysqli_query($dbConnect, "SELECT users.emailAddress, userInfo.fullName, userInfo.initials, userInfo.maxWorkspaces FROM users INNER JOIN userInfo ON userInfo.ID = users.ID WHERE users.ID = ".$localUser_id."");
        $queryResult = mysqli_fetch_array($dataQuery, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        $db_dash_userName   = $queryResult["fullName"];
        $db_dash_userEmail  = $queryResult["emailAddress"];
        $db_dash_userIcon   = "initials";
        $db_dash_userMaxW   = $queryResult["maxWorkspaces"];
        $db_dash_userInit   = $queryResult["initials"];

        return $db_dash_userName.$db_dash_userEmail.$db_dash_userIcon.$db_dash_userMaxW.$db_dash_userInit."<br><br><br>";

    }

    //$localUser_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
    $localUser_id = 1;
    $output = fetchUserData($localUser_id);

    echo $output;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'd recommend using the implode() function to separate out the new values :)

Comment: @RyanCastle are you saying you want to use implode function before display?

Comment: @RyanCastle you could return array from the function and then implode the return value before display. If you want I can edit the answer to show that.